# Get large photos using Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm querying the facebook api to get albulm photos:

```
{album_id}/photos
```

where {album_id} is the ID of the album.

How do I make sure the pictures returned are large enough?

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the photos in different sizes:

```
/{album-id}/photos?fields=images
```